# Is single rest 'put' endpoint enough to update a document with nested arrays?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, rest, mongoose, lodash

[I am copying the exact question from last year which still has not been answered, and extend it a bit]

I'm developing a REST api using node.js + mongoose (MEAN.io). I have a model which has few nested arrays within it. I have a put endpoint to update the document. However to add an object into the sub-array, do I need a separate endpoint or is there a way to use the same put endpoint?

```
companyName: String,
city: String,
pincode: Number,
managers: [{
    name: String,
    dob: Date,
    gender: String,         
    highestEducation: String,
    email: String,
    phoneNumbers: [{phoneNumber: Number}],
}],
```

I have an endpoint ../api/customer for updating the document. It replaces the existing document with the json that I'm supplying. So, if I want to add a manager (not replace the existing manager), do I need a separate endpoint just for this? What is the optimized solution?

At the moment, I have created another put api like this:

```
../api/customer/:id/managers
```

and at the server side of api, I am using  *customer.managers.push(updates);* instead of *_.merge(customer, updates)*.

Comment: What you do with the data depends on your db model structure as well has how you expect UI to work. Hard for anyone to help without more detail. we don't know if you have separate model for manager for example...and if you do whether UI should save to db through it's own endpoint before it gets displayed as part of a customer

Comment: let's say customer is the only model. In terms of UI, let's say whenever i show a customer, i need also to show all the managers and their phone numbers. So i have just one model for all. (btw, otherwise i would of course put more details to the question, but as like this, you should not need more info)

Comment: So based on that then manager would always be in customer document so sounds like don't even have to parse what is sent to customer endpoint...just store it

Comment: i think you did not get the point.. let's say i want to add another phone number for an existing manager of an existing customer. So how?

Answer (score 0):

Your API design is ultimately your choice. Personally I prefer to keep things quite shallow, maybe one relationship deep if that. Generally I will have an endpoint per resource.

In terms of your example about the new phone number for existing manager for an existing customer. A general flow using a somewhat shallow api could be:

- Frontend:

  - Goto URL site/users/1 (this loads up the basic view for the user).
- API:

  - Action: GET
  - Url: site/api/v1/users/1
  - Desc: SHOW user 1
  - Response: `{ id: 1, name: "bob", age: 22 }`
- API:

  - Action: GET
  - Url: site/api/v1/managers?query=user_id=1
  - Desc: INDEX all manager for user 1
  - Response: `{ [ { id: 55, name: "mana1", phone: 4444 }, { id: 66, name: "mana2", phone: 333 }, .. ] }`
- Frontend: List managers as a bunch of forms with some hidden id's
- Frontend: Enter phone number hit save
- API:

  - Action: PATCH
  - Url: site/api/v1/managers/55
  - BODY: `{ phone: 9898 }`
  - Desc: PATCH manager 55 with new phone data
  - Response: { ..updated data.. }

I personally really like this for API's:
https://github.com/WhiteHouse/api-standards

It's not rest, but its simple, repeatable and usable.

Comment: so if you had 10 different dokument types which are somehow connected to eachother, although you always need to read them together from the database (in my case: frontend:  let's say whenever i show a customer, i need also to show all the managers and their phone numbers), you would still make a different api call for each.. so 10 GET api calls. sorry. i dont agree with you.

Comment: No you wouldn't? Just use /site/api/v1/managers?query=user_id=1 This would return X managers with one call? Its the second API dot point